# Floats not working correctly

Tags: css

Here's my homepage that I've put together http://jsfiddle.net/u5VkN/ and as you can see there is a div called #login-box that is in the wrong place.

Where it's meant to go is to the right of the #signup-box within the #mainFrame.

Any ideas what is up? I think it's my misunderstanding of floats. The div has enough width set for it to sit to the right and it floated to the left so it comes just after #signup-box

Thanks

CSS:

```
#signup-box{
width: 560px;
height: 250px;
font-size: 18px;
float: left;
clear: both;
}

#login-box{
width: 200px;
height: 250px;
float: left;
clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you have them both set to `clear:both`,set the `#signup-box` to `clear:left` and `#login-box` to `clear:right` and you should be fine

Comment: Awesome thanks. Also if you look at the same code (and also here http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/salesboard/Salesboard_Mainpage.html) do you know why #mainFrame isn't holding all of the divs inside of it? As you can see it's gone upwards a few pixels.

Comment: probably an overflow thing, set `overflow:auto` on the mainframe should fix it, should have a look at this site http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/ explains floats well I think...

Comment: Great, looks like a really useful article. Appreciate your help.